# Comprehensive comparison of SLAM algorithms

Tags: slam, reference-request

I'm looking for a research paper or series of papers that compare the performance of various simultaneous localization and mapping algorithms for rovers in a variety of real world environments.  In particular, i'm looking for computational speed, accuracy (compared to the real world environment) and memory & power efficiency metrics.  Is there a journal that regularly publishes experimental performance comparisons?

Answer (score 3):

The [Journal of Field Robotics](http://www.journalfieldrobotics.org/Home.html) is likely the closest to what you are asking for. Its one of the highest ranked journals in robotics, and requires the articles to have a significant part of field experiments. I don't recall a comprehensive SLAM survey article, though.

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful

[An evaluation of 2D SLAM techniques available in Robot Operating System](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6719348&tag=1)